# How to import variables between files with LESS - currently getting 'undefined'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Hey I'm relatively new to bootstrap and am trying to import bootstraps responsive css into my style.less file.

i.e

```
@import "css/bootstrap-responsive.css";
```

I'm then applying the following

```
#menu, #sub-menu {
.span2;
color: @bodydarker1;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 1%;
}
```

And `.span2;` appears in bootstrap-responsive.css but when i check the pages its giving me the message..

```
    .span2 is undefined
in style.less on line 26, column 2:
```

Now if I applied the colour red to the body in bootstrap-responsive.css it would render that fine but when I call in the class `.span2` its saying that its undefined. Why would that be?

If I add `.span2` as a class in the html that will work, but applying to an id when imported on the less document won't.

Comment: You should import the less files, not the css files.

Comment: import the less into the css?

Comment: No, obviously not. Import the `.less` into a *`.less`* file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to import the .less file rather then the .css. You **can** import .css, I'd only recommend always working from .less files. You may run into a lot more issues while importing the .css rather than the .less.

It looks like your .LESS code structure is just a tad incorrect. Try replacing this:

```
#menu, #sub-menu {
.span2;
color: @bodydarker1;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
padding: 1%;
}
```

with this:

```
#menu, 
#sub-menu {
    .span2 {
        color: @bodydarker1;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        padding: 1%;
    }
}
```

**edit:**

If you're trying to access .span2 under your custom #menu id then you'll have to see what [namespace](http://lesscss.org/#-namespaces) it's under in the bootstrap (if it's under a namespace) and then adjust accordingly.

Example

```
#bootstrap {
    #lists {
        .span2 {
            // some span2 stuff
        }
    }
}

#menu, 
#sub-menu {
    #bootstrap > #lists > .span2;

    color: @bodydarker1;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
}
```